# Logstash Messy CSV File

Tags: regex, csv, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to use *Logstash* and *grok* to parse a messy *CSV* file.

I was using the *CSV filter* originally but it meant I had to remove a bunch of header data in pre-processing first.

Ideally I'd like to use the *CSV filter* again due to its simplicity. I have no control of how the *CSV* files arrive. Ideally I'd like *Logstash* to handle everything without any pre-processing.

Below is an example of my *CSV* file:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
"text"
"text"

"01-Jan-2012"
"0123456789"

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

"col1Header",[...],col17Header"
"col1UoM",[...],col17UoM"

01-Jan-2012 11:00:01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01-Jan-2012 11:00:02,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01-Jan-2012 11:00:03,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
01-Jan-2012 11:00:04,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

This is my *Logstash* configuration, it produces the error shown in the comments:

```
input{
file{
    path => ["/opt/docs/*"]
    type => "log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    ignore_older => 0
    }
}
filter{
    grok{
        # error being returned here
        # error is: "Expected one of #, {, } at line 27, column 110 (byte 906) after filter{\n\t\n\n\t
# the regex following is to match all the header data that I don't want.
        match => {"header_data" => "(?<header_data>[0-9].*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*"\n)"}
    } # my plan was to then drop the header_data field (not implemented) and the data would be sent to the csv filter
    csv{
        columns => ["col17Header",[...],"col17Header]
    }
    mutate{
        convert => {"col2" => "float",[...] => "float","col17" => "float"}
    }
    date{
        match => ["col1","dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"]
    }
}


output{
    elasticsearch{
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["192.168.1.118:9200"]
        index => "foo-logs"
    }
}
```

For clarity here is the error being produced:

> "Expected one of #, {, } at line 27, column 110 (byte 906) after
>   filter{\n\t\n\n\t
>       # the regex following is to match all the header data that I don't want.
>             match => {"header_data" => "(?[0-9].*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*"\n)"}

I'd like to remove all the data above the dated 4 lines at the bottom. I made (what I assume are inefficient) *regex* patterns to find the header and *CSV* data.

All I need from the *CSV* file are the last 4 lines in my example file, that's all the data I need.

My thoughts are that I'm currently not going about doing this the right way, so I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, the lines you want have a unique pattern:

```
^%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR}
```

grok for that pattern.  For the lines that don't match, you'll get a grokparsefailure and can then use the drop{} filter to ignore them.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! 

Just for clarification for other readers, this is the part of my config that I altered and added in: `filter{
 grok{
  match => {"message" => "^%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR}"}
 }
 if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
  drop {} 
 }
 csv{`

My real issue was I never understood that if a grok pattern matched a part of the line then it matched the rest of the event and passed it through in the "message" field to the next filter, the CSV filter in my case.

P.S. I'd upvote your answer but my n00bish reputation doesn't allow it.